# FFMPEG android reduce the video rendering time

Tags: android, ffmpeg, encoding, rendering, video-encoding

```
cmd = "-y "+"-i "+ inputVideo.getAbsolutePath()+" -i "+ inputImage.getAbsolutePath()+  " -filter_complex [1:v]scale=50:200[ovr1],[0:v][ovr1]overlay=5:5:enable='between(t\\,"+0+"\\,"+20+")' -preset ultrafast -c:a aac " + outputVideo.getAbsolutePath();
```

I'm using this command in FFMPEG to render an image to a video in android. And using this > https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit library.

But the thing is either I use preset "ultrafast" or "veryslow" as mentioned in [trac.ffmpeg.org](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264), it doesn't show any difference (rendering speeds are same in both instances). No any errors are shown either. So am I doing something wrong here or is there any other way to reduce the rendering time?

Comment: how are you executing that command I mean like are you using FFMPEG kit? are you using Coroutines or Executors? Providing more details will help u get answers quickly

Comment: Yes as mentioned I'm using FFMPEG-KIT and >>  `FFmpegKit.executeAsync(cmd, new FFmpegSessionCompleteCallback() {` to execute the command.

Comment: try running this block of code inside of Coroutine scope with IO Dispatcher it will be much faster I myself have used the same FFMPEG Kit to replace the audio of a video with another audio and it works flawlessly.

Comment: So the thing here is that the execution of the command happens fine but this `-preset` is not working as expected. other than that the command runs fine. It takes like 10 seconds to render a 30 second video. Looking for a way to see if there's a way to reduce more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to specify the ffmpeg-kit package that support H 264 commands.
could achieve it by adding below to the build gradle

```
    ext {
        ffmpegKitPackage = "min-gpl"
    }
```